# Can I use elisp code make a table and insert a variable into cell?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Can I insert a variable 'alpha' into @2$3 ? Does the function belong Emacs org?

```org
** test elisp make a table
#+name: make-table
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results value
(setq tol 0.1)
(setq alpha 1.38)
(setq alpha_1 (- 90 alpha))
'(("angle" "symbol"   "value"  "max"         "min") hline 
  ("toe"   "\\alpha"   alpha  (+ alpha tol)  (- alpha tol))
  ("c"   "\\alpha_1"   alpha_1  (+ alpha_1 tol)  (- alpha_1 tol))
 )
#+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there. You just have to apply [backquotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) instead of single-quote for quoting and comma-operators where you want to insert the variable values.
That is not org-mode specific but standard-lisp stuff.

```el
** test elisp make a table
#+name: make-table
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results value
(setq tol 0.1)
(setq alpha 1.38)
(setq alpha_1 (- 90 alpha))
`(("angle" "symbol"   "value"  "max"         "min") hline 
  ("toe"   "\\alpha"   ,alpha  ,(+ alpha tol)  ,(- alpha tol))
  ("c"   "\\alpha_1"   ,alpha_1  ,(+ alpha_1 tol)  ,(- alpha_1 tol))
  )
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: make-table
| angle | symbol   | value |   max |                min |
|-------+----------+-------+-------+--------------------|
| toe   | \alpha   |  1.38 |  1.48 | 1.2799999999999998 |
| c     | \alpha_1 | 88.62 | 88.72 |  88.52000000000001 |
```

Comment: Thanks,I can't find a sample in ORG guide so ask here.Thanks again.Emacs and Elisp is great.

Comment: Would there be a way to not call the results `#+RESULTS: make-table` rather `#+TBLNAME: make-table`? In general, is it possible to tell a code block ahead of time to send the results to a declared variable?

Comment: @147pm I hope I understood your question right. It is of general value. So I posted it as separate question at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/48972/2370. You also find an answer there.