# Naming the result of a source block

Tags: org-babel, org-table

The following question has been asked (in slightly different form) in [a comment of another answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37478/can-i-use-elisp-code-make-a-table-and-insert-a-variable-into-cell/37479?noredirect=1#comment75900_37479):

Is it possible to name the results of a source block with `#+NAME: foobar` (or equivalently but old-style: `#+TBLNAME: foobar`) rather than `#+RESULTS: foobar`?

Example:

```
#+NAME: foo
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var alpha=2 :results value
(let* ((tol 0.1)
       (alpha_1 (- 90 alpha)))
  `(("angle" "symbol"   "value"  "max"         "min") hline 
    ("toe"   "\\alpha"   ,alpha  ,(+ alpha tol)  ,(- alpha tol))
    ("c"   "\\alpha_1"   ,alpha_1  ,(+ alpha_1 tol)  ,(- alpha_1 tol))
    ))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: foo
| angle | symbol   | value |  max |  min |
|-------+----------+-------+------+------|
| toe   | \alpha   |     1 |  1.1 |  0.9 |
| c     | \alpha_1 |    89 | 89.1 | 88.9 |
```

Answer (score 2):

One can add the following lines below unnamed source blocks (with `bar` replaced by the intended table name):

```
#+NAME: bar
#+RESULTS:
||
```

The line with `#+name: bar` is preserved after the evaluation of the source block and `||` is replaced with the resulting table.

Note, that the name `bar` really names the table and not the source block.
That has the following consequences (probably among others I am not aware of at the moment):

1. If you refer to the table name in the header arguments of another source block, say `buh`, then the `bar` source block is not reevaluated when `buh` is evaluated. The table is not updated but taken as argument for `buh` as it is.
   That is usually more an disadvantage than an advantage.
   One can call `org-babel-execute-buffer` to get correctly updated results.
2. If the source block returns a string containing the formatted org-table rather than table data referring to the source block name in header variables gets you the string and not the table data. That is most often unwanted.
   In that case it is a big advantage that you can alternatively refer to the resulting table by its name.

If the source block is named, e.g., `foo` replace `#+RESULTS:` with `#+RESULTS: foo`.

Example:

```
#+NAME: foo
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var alpha=2 :results value
(let* ((tol 0.1)
       (alpha_1 (- 90 alpha)))
  `(("angle" "symbol"   "value"  "max"         "min") hline 
    ("toe"   "\\alpha"   ,alpha  ,(+ alpha tol)  ,(- alpha tol))
    ("c"   "\\alpha_1"   ,alpha_1  ,(+ alpha_1 tol)  ,(- alpha_1 tol))
    ))
#+END_SRC

#+TBLNAME: bar
#+RESULTS: foo
| angle | symbol   | value |  max |  min |
|-------+----------+-------+------+------|
| toe   | \alpha   |     1 |  1.1 |  0.9 |
| c     | \alpha_1 |    89 | 89.1 | 88.9 |

#+CALL: foo(alpha=bar[2,3])

#+NAME: buh
#+RESULTS:
| angle | symbol   | value |                max |               min |
|-------+----------+-------+--------------------+-------------------|
| toe   | \alpha   |   1.1 | 1.2000000000000002 |               1.0 |
| c     | \alpha_1 |  88.9 |               89.0 | 88.80000000000001 |
```

The example demonstrates the update problem. The header variable `alpha` had the value 1 at the first evaluation of `foo`. Afterwards the value was changed to 2 but the source block `foo` was not evaluated again.
The evaluation of the `#+CALL` statement does use the table value 1.1 at cell `2,3` directly without reevaluation of `foo`.

Comment: Quite informative, indeed. But there seems to be no way to not have the line `#+RESULTS:` in the results. One interesting question is, how is the system handling a `let*` form and turning it into a table? Is this something to do with `:results value`? But then if I do `#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var table=bar
  (message "%S" table) #+end_src` I get  `(("toe" "\\alpha" 2 2.1 1.9) ("c" "$\\alpha_1$" 88 88.1 87.9))` i.e., it's left out the title and horizontal line, i.e.,i.e., not completely reversible? Interesting stuff, nonetheless.